# java struts2 weird serialization behavior (rounds big numbers by its self)

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, biginteger, json-rpc

i've the next isolated test case scenario

```
@SMDMethod
public BigInteger getSomeReallyBigInteger() {
    return new BigInteger("154456875042019001");
}
```

this is the action at struts.xml

```
    <action name="DataSourceRpc" class="isoblock.struts2.action.DataSourceAction" method="smd">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param> 
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

im calling the SMD function using a JSON-RPC implentation (using dojo-rpc), this is the failure,

when i call the last function the result callback its:

- 154456875042019000

instead of

- 154456875042019001

this happens only with big numbers (all with 17 or more dijits), im using **struts2-json-plugin-2.3.8.jar** (latest)

so, its this an **struts2** bug??

greetings,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that numbers in Javascript are double-precision floats, which cannot represent 154456875042019001 accurately.  Double-precision floats have 15-17 digits of precision and you have 18 digits.  When converted to a float and back again some precision is lost.

For example, in Perl:

```
$a=154456875042019001.0;
printf "%20d",$a;
```

outputs

```
154456875042019008
```

Further details:

The hexadecimal representation of `154456875042019001`<sub>10</sub> is `0x0224bdb5a1ff16b9`, which contains 58 significant bits (in binary it starts `0000 0010 0010 0100 ...`, so 64 minus 6 leading zero bits).  Double-precision float has 52 bits of precision, so some bits are lost when converting the 64-bit `long` to the `double`.

Comment: hm, so this means i have to return maybe an string instead of a number?? thanks :)

Comment: That would be one way to do it, and probably the best one.